# Simplifying exponential expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the following equaiton
$$
\frac{x^{a}}{y^{b}}=c
$$

I wish to get an expression for $\frac{x}{y}$. I am proceeding in
the following way:
$$
x^{a}=cy^{b}
$$
$$
x=c^{\frac{1}{a}}y^{\frac{b}{a}}
$$
The issue is that I cannot seem to get a clean expression for $\frac{x}{y}$.
Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that you're going to be able to get a particularly "clean" expression for $\frac{x}{y}$ unless we are in a special case where $a=b$. Do you have a particular definition for "clean"?

Comment: My mistake. I wanted to get an expression for x/y as a function only of c.

Comment: @KwameBrown  I added extended/expanded context to the answer .

Answer (score 6):

I interpreted your *exact* statement as follows :

> Let $\thinspace a,b,c\thinspace $ be some fixed real numbers, such that $\thinspace\dfrac {x^a}{y^b}=c\thinspace$ holds . Then, determine ( if possible ) the *unique* value of $\thinspace \dfrac xy\thinspace .$

In this answer, I will show that :

> For all fixed triple $\thinspace(a,b,c)\in\mathbb R^{3}\thinspace$ with $\thinspace a≠b\wedge c>0\thinspace$, there exist infinitely many different $\thinspace\left\{\dfrac xy\right\}\in\mathbb R^{+}\thinspace$, such that $\thinspace\dfrac {x^a}{y^b}=\thinspace c$ always holds .

---

$\rm\bf{ Proof }$

We will assume that, $\thinspace xy>0\thinspace$ and $\thinspace x≠y\thinspace$ for our purposes .

You can observe that, there is no way to isolate the expression $\thinspace \dfrac xy\thinspace$, as we wish. It seems possible to me, if and only if, when $\thinspace a=b≠0\thinspace$ .

Indeed, we have :

$$
\begin{align}&\frac {x^a}{y^a}=\left(\frac xy\right)^a=c\\
\implies &\frac xy=c^{\frac 1a}\end{align}
$$

However, if $\thinspace a≠b\wedge a≠0\thinspace$ or $\thinspace a≠b\wedge b≠0\thinspace$, then you have :

$$
\begin{align}&\frac {x^a}{y^b}=\left(\frac xy\right)^ay^{a-b}=c\\
\implies &\left(\frac xy\right)^a=cy^{b-a}\\
\implies &\frac xy=c^{1/a}y^{b/a -1}\end{align}
$$

or

$$
\begin{align}&\frac {x^a}{y^b}=\left(\frac xy\right)^
bx^{a-b}=c\\
\implies &\left(\frac xy\right)^b=cx^{b-a}\\
\implies &\frac xy=c^{1/b}x^{1-a/b }\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

Then, let $\thinspace \dfrac xy=\alpha\in\mathbb R_{+}\setminus \{1\}\thinspace$ be an arbitrary real number with given constants $\thinspace(a,b,c)\in\mathbb R^{3}\wedge a≠b\wedge c>0\thinspace$, then we have :

$$
\begin{align}&\alpha=\frac xy=c^{1/b}x^{1-a/b }\\
\implies &x=\left(\alpha c^{-1/b}\right)^{\frac {b}{b-a}}\\
&\space\thinspace\thinspace=\alpha^{\frac {b}{b-a}}c^{\frac {1}{a-b}}\\
\implies &y=\frac {x}{\alpha} \\
&\space\thinspace\thinspace=\alpha^{\frac {a}{b-a}}c^{\frac {1}{a-b}}\thinspace.\end{align}
$$

---

Thus, the following constructed pair $\thinspace(x,y)\thinspace$ proves our statement :

$$
\begin{align}\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{(x,y)=\left(\alpha^{\frac {b}{b-a}}c^{\frac {1}{a-b}},\thinspace \alpha^{\frac {a}{b-a}}c^{\frac {1}{a-b}}\right)}\end{align}
$$

which completes the answer .

Comment: A really good way of making the question precise!

Comment: The change you've made has significantly altered the question.

Comment: @CroCo I added extended/expanded context to the answer .